# Eliminate Circular Recursion in Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am new to lightswitch development, so far I immensely dislike it. I have the following problem:

I have a table called employees, each employee has a boss which is also an employee. I would like to present a user with a choice of bosses which does not allow for any circular recursion, so for example if I want to select person A's boss, then person B would not be shown if person A is person B's boss.

I can write all the code to do this, my problem is I can't figure out how to populate a control of some-sort from a method, could someone please give me a step-by-step guide.

**As per the request of "Mikko Viitala"**

I wouldn't mind binding the control to a dynamically generated list that whose contents are loaded from the employee's table and checked for validity with the following function:

```
// Checks for circular recursion, retuns true if safe.
public static bool CheckForCircularRecursion(Employee emp)
{
    if (emp.Boss != null && emp.Id == emp.Boss.Id)
        return false;
    return CheckForCircularRecursion_Inner(emp, emp);
}

// Returns true if safe
private static bool CheckForCircularRecursion_Inner(Employee original, Employee emp)
{
    if (emp.Boss == null)
        return true;
    else if (emp.Boss == original)
        return false;
    else
        return CheckForCircularRecursion_Inner(original, emp.Boss);
}
```

Comment: Updated it with my code, don't see how it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Morgoth - though you broke my heart when you said you don't like LightSwitch :( - I'm going to try and hopefully change your mind.

Are you trying to just populate some Silverlight Control programatically from some screen method?
Is this a custom control? If so have you read anything like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674919.aspx

Beth Massi has some good articles on populating Lists 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/09/15/filtering-lookup-lists-with-large-amounts-of-data-on-data-entry-screens.aspx

You should be able to filter our the data from the list that isn't relevant to the employee (which I believe Beth does in the article)